# Assigning a pointer the address of another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am very confused as to what the following code means. In `somefunction` the parameter is a pointer to a struct node. In the main the argument I am putting in is the address location of another pointer called A. So what does that exactly mean? What is the difference between A and B? Do A and B represent the same pointer? Does B now point to C after the line `(*B)=C`?

```
struct node{
    int value;
};

void somefunction(Struct node *B)
{
    struct node *C = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    (*B)=C;
};

main()
{
    struct node *A;
    somefunction(&A);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `void somefunction(struct node **B)`?  (with two '*'s)

Comment: that's what I thought too, but apparently it's not. I checked the code my professor posted again and it's just *B. That one line, *B is really confusing me. If it was **B then it would make sense to me.

Comment: Maybe your professor isn't as smart as he should be .. :\

Comment: If it's not `**`, turn up your compiler warnings and add a flag to abort on a warning (eg `-Wall -Werror`).  That code only compiles if the compiler is being very lenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass by pointer, you want changes made within a function to be visible to the caller:

```
struct node {
    int value;
};

void foo(struct node* n) {
    n->value = 7;
}

struct node n;
foo(&n);
// n.value is 7 here
```

and you pass an address of a pointer when you want to change the pointer itself:

```
void createNode(struct node** n) {
    *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}

struct node* nodePtr;
foo(&nodePtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this Modified and commented code will help you in understanding.

```
// Step-3
// Catching address so we need pointer but we are passing address of pointer so we need
// variable which can store address of pointer type variable.
// So in this case we are using struct node **
//now B contains value_in_B : 1024
void somefunction(struct node **B)
{
    // Step-4
    // Assuming malloc returns 6024
    // assume address_of_C : 4048
    // and   value_in_C : 6024 //return by malloc
    struct node *C = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // Step-5
    // now we want to store value return by malloc, in 'A' ie at address 1024.
    // So we have the address of A ie 1024 stored in 'B' now using dereference we can store value 6024 at that address
    (*B)=C;
};

int main()
{
    // Step-1
    // assume address_of_A : 1024
    // and   value_in_A : NULL
    struct node *A = NULL;

    // Step-2
    // Passing 1024 ie address
    somefunction(&A);

    // After execution of above stepv value_in_A : 6024
    return 0;
}
```